# Write right schema for Propel ORM One to Many and One to One relationship?

Tags: php, database, orm, schema, propel

My question is why when I run `propel diff` I am getting error

`vendor\bin\propel diff  In Table.php line 796:    Table "product_product_category" contains a foreign key to table "product_category" but does not have a reference to foreign primary key "place_id"`.

Here is my schema.xml:

```
`    <table name="product" phpName="Product" identifierQuoting="true">
    <column name="id" type="integer" required="true" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true"/>
    <column name="name" type="varchar" size="32" required="true" phpName="Name"/>
    <column name="description" type="varchar" size="500" required="true" phpName="Description"/>

    <column name="photo_name" type="varchar" size="32" required="false" phpName="PhotoName"/>

    <column name="is_active" type="BOOLEAN" required="true" defaultValue="false" phpName="Active" phpType = "boolean"/>

    <column name="price" type="integer" required="true" phpName="Price"/>

    <column name="place_id" type="integer" required="true" phpName="CurrentPlaceId"/>
    <foreign-key foreignTable="place" phpName="CurrentPlace" refPhpName="CurrentPlaceProduct" onDelete="CASCADE">
        <reference local="place_id" foreign="id"/>
    </foreign-key>


    <column name="measurement_type_id" type="integer" required="true" phpName="CurrentMeasurementTypeId"/>
    <foreign-key foreignTable="measurement_type" phpName="CurrentMeasurementType" refPhpName="CurrentMeasurementTypeProduct">
        <reference local="measurement_type_id" foreign="id"/>
    </foreign-key>

    <column name="measurement" type="integer" defaultValue="0" phpName="Measurement"/>

    <behavior name="timestampable" />
    <behavior name="query_cache" />
</table>
<table name="place" phpName="Place" identifierQuoting="true">
    <column name="id" type="integer" required="true" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true"/>
    <column name="name" type="varchar" size="32" required="true" phpName="Name"/>
    <column name="alt_name" type="varchar" size="32" required="true" phpName="AltName"/>
    <column name="description" type="varchar" size="1000" required="false" phpName="Description"/>
    <column name="logo_name" type="varchar" size="32" required="false" phpName="LogoName"/>
    <column name="cover_name" type="varchar" size="32" required="false" phpName="CoverName"/>
    <column name="min_order_amount" type="integer" required="true" phpName="MinOrderAmount"/>
    <column name="delivery_cost" type="integer" required="true" phpName="DeliveryCost"/>
    <column name="is_active" type="BOOLEAN" required="true" defaultValue="false" phpName="Active" phpType = "boolean"/>
    <column name="address" type="varchar" size="100" required="true" phpName="Address"/>
    <column name="address_coordinates" type="ARRAY" required="false" phpName="AddressCoordinates"/>

    <column name="around_the_clock" type="BOOLEAN" required="true" defaultValue="false" phpName="AroundTheClock" phpType = "boolean"/>
    <column name="week_days" type="ARRAY" required="true" phpName="WeekDays"/>
    <column name="work_start_time" type="TIME" required="false" phpName="WorkStartTime"/>
    <column name="work_end_time" type="TIME" required="false" phpName="WorkEndTime"/>

    <column name="phones" type="ARRAY" required="true" phpName="Phones"/>

    <column name="place_admin_id" type="integer" required="true" phpName="CurrentPlaceAdminId"/>
    <foreign-key foreignTable="user" phpName="CurrentPlaceAdmin" refPhpName="CurrentPlaceAdminPlace" onDelete="CASCADE">
        <reference local="place_admin_id" foreign="id"/>
    </foreign-key>


    <column name="payment_type_id" type="integer" required="true" phpName="CurrentPaymentTypeId"/>
    <foreign-key foreignTable="payment_type" phpName="CurrentPaymentType" refPhpName="CurrentPaymentTypePlace">
        <reference local="payment_type_id" foreign="id"/>
    </foreign-key>


    <column name="delivery_time_type_id" type="integer" required="true" phpName="CurrentDeliveryTimeTypeId"/>
    <foreign-key foreignTable="delivery_time_type" phpName="CurrentDeliveryTimeType" refPhpName="CurrentDeliveryTimeTypePlace">
        <reference local="delivery_time_type_id" foreign="id"/>
    </foreign-key>

    <column name="average_cheque" type="integer" required="false" phpName="AvarageCheque"/>

    <behavior name="timestampable" />
    <behavior name="query_cache" />
    <behavior name="archivable" />
</table>
<table name="product_category" phpName="ProductCategory" identifierQuoting="true">
  <column name="id" type="integer" required="true" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true"/>
  <column name="name" type="varchar" size="20" phpName="Name"/>
  <column name="alt_name" type="varchar" phpName="AltName"/>
  <column name="description" type="varchar" size="300" phpName="Description"/>

  <column name="place_id" type="integer" primaryKey="true" phpName="CurrentPlaceId"/>
  <foreign-key foreignTable="place" onDelete="CASCADE" phpName="CurrentPlace" refPhpName="CurrentPlaceProductCategory">
    <reference local="place_id" foreign="id"/>
  </foreign-key>

  <behavior name="sortable" />
</table>
<table name="product_product_category" phpName="ProductCategoryProduct" isCrossRef="true">

    <column name="product_category_id" type="integer" primaryKey="true"/>
    <foreign-key foreignTable="product_category" phpName="CurrentProductCategoryProductCategoryProduct" refPhpName="CurrentProductCategoryProductCategoryProduct" onDelete="CASCADE">
      <reference local="product_category_id" foreign="id"/>
    </foreign-key>


  <column name="product_id" type="integer" primaryKey="true"/>
  <foreign-key foreignTable="product" phpName="CurrentProductProductCategoryProduct" refPhpName="CurrentProductProductCategoryProduct" onDelete="CASCADE">
    <reference local="product_id" foreign="id"/>
  </foreign-key>


</table>`
```

Please help me I have added even `place_id` foreign key to the `product_product_category`, but it still gives error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I have found my mistake,
on the table `product_category` I had written by mistake `primaryKey="true"` on the `<column name="place_id" type="integer" primaryKey="true" phpName="CurrentPlaceId"/>` . Just needed to delete it